# What features of WPF are excluded in Silverlight 3?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

What WPF features were removed from Silverlight 3 ?  I have found resources on graphing algorithms in WPF and am wondering how much of that I can transfer to a Silverlight application.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: IMO the question isn't technically accurate, as Silverlight is a separate platform than WPF. We didn't "start" with the WPF codebase and start removing pieces to build Silverlight - but instead chose to remain compatible in many ways but built an entirely different native stack for Silverlight.

As a result, it's really an insane task to "port" a WPF app to Silverlight... but moving Silverlight to WPF is possible and easy. It's more of a one-way conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be difficult to describe the differences exhaustively here, suffice to say they are considerable.  Here are a couple of links that might help:-

[XAML Processing Differences Between Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917841(VS.95).aspx)

[Guidance on Differences Between WPF and Silverlight](http://wpfslguidance.codeplex.com/)

Bear in mind also that even common types in the silverlight core libraries may be missing or have missing features compared with those of the primary .NET library counterparts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I will review these links.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the 3D manipulation routines in Silverlight (esp. anything involving DirectX) can't be done in the silverlight plugin, so depending on what your graphing algorithm requires you may be out of luck, sorry to say.

But Microsoft has ported quite a bit of WPF to Silverlight 3 and I think the pleasant surprises will outnumber the unpleasant ones.  If you're doing simple raster or vector graphing you may be able to pull it off.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  The algorithms are mostly 2D and would not require DirectDraw or DirectX 3D.  I imagine for 3D perspectives this can be faked with pseudo 3D in Silverlight 3.